# Can't get ImageMagick working after macports selfupdate

Tags: imagemagick, macports

Ok. so yesterday foolishly decided to update my libraries with macports. I did a self-update to 1.9.2. Then, my rails application started failing because rmagick couldn't talk to ImageMagick anymore. So, I backed it out. Then, macports wouldn't install ImageMagick because of a problem with ncursesw.

So, I removed each macport item by hand. I just ran

```
sudo port install ImageMagick
```

and got the following error:

...

--->  Installing libiconv @1.13.1_0
--->  Activating libiconv @1.13.1_0
--->  Cleaning libiconv
--->  Building ncursesw
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
Error: Failed to install ncursesw
Log for ncursesw is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_ncursesw/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: autoconf help2man gettext ncurses ncursesw p5-locale-gettext perl5 perl5.8 m4 automake bzip2 fontconfig freetype zlib ghostscript jpeg libidn libpaper libpng libtool pkgconfig tiff xorg-libXext xorg-libX11 xorg-bigreqsproto xorg-inputproto xorg-kbproto xorg-libXau xorg-xproto xorg-libXdmcp xorg-libxcb python26 db46 gdbm openssl readline sqlite3 xorg-libpthread-stubs xorg-xcb-proto libxml2 xorg-util-macros xorg-xcmiscproto xorg-xextproto xorg-xf86bigfontproto xorg-xtrans xorg-libXt xorg-libsm xorg-libice lcms p7zip
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened but I just reloaded OS X and recreated all my port installs. Something was screwed somewhere from the self update.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific with "reloaded OS X" and "recreated all my port installs". I am having the same error and a tough time figuring it out.